# Custom product page layout -> single-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to create my own custom product page layout but i got some error with below code.
The file is saved in child theme -> single-product.php

I cant get product id...

```
<?php

get_header();
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
the_title( '<h2 class="product_title entry-title"></h2>' );

global $product;
global $post;

$short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
?>

<h1><?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?></h1> // -> Its not working

<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
    <?php echo $short_description; ?>
</div>


<form class="cart" action="https://a.tomaszthiel.pl/produkt/produkt-1/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="iconic-engraving-field">
    <label for="iconic-engraving">Engraving (10 characters)</label>
    <input type="text" id="iconic-engraving" name="iconic-engraving" placeholder="Enter engraving text" maxlength="10">
    </div>      
    <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="14" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt wp-element-button">Dodaj do koszyka</button>
</form>

<?php
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
get_footer(); 

?>
```

Im trying to get product id from product page.

Comment: Why are you not following the logic of the original template file? It loops over the posts there and calls `teh_post()`, after which inside that loop you should be able to use the usual things such as `get_the_ID` etc. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php#L34

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.